# Issues getting data from a database in php

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have been on this issue for a while now, having tried everything from the code you would see below and not getting any result.

Here is the database i created and is finally updating;

I have been on this issue for a while now, having tried everything from the code you would see below and not getting any result.

Here is the database i created and is finally updating;

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['message'] = '';
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'accounts');


if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
echo "Connected successfully";

// sql to create table
//$sql = "CREATE TABLE Added (
//id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
//name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
//email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
//address VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
//phone VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
//district VARCHAR(50),
//reg_date TIMESTAMP
//)";

//if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
//echo "Table Added created successfully";
//} else {
//echo "Error creating table: " . $mysqli->error;
//}




if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

    //two passwords are equal to each other

    $name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $emailErr = "Invalid email format";
    }
    $phone = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $address = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $district = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['district']);
//make sure file type is image

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Added (name, email, phone, address, district) "
        . "VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$phone', '$address', '$district')";


    if ($mysqli->query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;
    }


}
//if the query is successful, redirect to welcome
```

And here is the code to try retrieving all the user data;

PHP:

```
<?php
// Get user data
// sort the data based on the district
// customize the message, concatinate the username with the message.
// then send the message.
    session_start();
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'accounts');

    if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->connect_error);
    }
    echo "Connected successfully";
$json = array( );
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Added",$mysqli) or die (mysql_error());
while( $users = mysql_fetch_assoc( $sql ) ) {
    $json[] = $users;
}
echo json_encode( $json );
var_dump($users);

//$query= $mysqli->query($sql);
//$arr = mysql_fetch_array($query);
//$num = mysql_numrows($query);
    //$array = [{
       //name: "Chisimdi Damian",
        //id: 1
//},{

//}
//];

//$garki = [];
//$lokogoma = [];

    //foreach(i) {
        //$garki.push($item);
    //}
//var_dump($array);

I've been on these for some hours now and i'm in dire need to move ahead with my work.

I have commented out the not needed parts yet. I've tried all i know about selection, it just tells me connected successfully.

I have commented out the not needed parts yet. I've tried all i know about selection, it just tells me connected successfully.

I have commented out the not needed parts yet. I've tried all i know about selection, it just tells me connected successfully.
```

Comment: please please please switch to `PDO` or `mysqli prepared statements`!!!

Comment: True, NAME is a keyword, but now reserved.

Comment: @Moses What Qirel is trying so say is that you are mixing mysqli with deprecated mysql_* functions.

Comment: Ok i get it, but can anyone hint me on the mysqli function that would help me retrieve data for a start?